# Batch file to restart a service. Windows

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2003

How can I restart a windows service using a .bat file?
I am on windows server.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
net stop <your service> && net start <your service>
```

No `net restart`, unfortunately.

Comment: I think you mean only one `&`.

Comment: @vcsjones: "Brilliant?" :D It's not really that different... but thanks.

Comment: To me it is interesting, it short circuits. I never considered that a batch script could do that. The right doesn't execute if the %errorlevel% of the left is none zero. If you use a single `&`, then both execute regardless of the result of the left.

Comment: @vcsjones: Okay, well I didn't know that :)

Comment: What is the difference if you put it on two separate lines ?

Comment: @codea: If you put it on two separate lines, if the first one fails, the second one will still go through. (And then it’s also not a one-liner!)

Comment: Why not just:
`net stop <your service> <newline>
net start <your service>`
?
Just curious as to the meaning of the & there...

Comment: @PredragStojadinović: The `&&` means that if the `net stop` fails, the `net start` doesn’t run.

Comment: how to handle errors that may happen?